# ¿Como puedo actualizar el Panel con un JComboBox?

Tags: java, jpanel

Bueno mi motivo de esta pregunta es que no puedo lograr que mi panel se actualice cuando elijo una opción distinta del `JComboBox` solo es efectivo cuando lo realizo como primera opción del mismo `JComboBox`.

```
public void colocarComboBox(){
//Cambio de letra
tipoLetra = new JComboBox();
tipoLetra.addItem("Arial");
tipoLetra.addItem("Ubuntu");
tipoLetra.setBounds(200,10,100,30);
panel.add(tipoLetra);

//cambio de fondo
String [] Fondo ={"Negro","Azul","Amarillo","Blanco"};
fondoPanel = new JComboBox(Fondo);
String opcion = fondoPanel.getSelectedItem().toString();
fondoPanel.setBounds(320,10,100,30);
panel.add(fondoPanel);

if(opcion.equals("Negro")){
    panel.updateUI();
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
}
if(opcion.equals("Azul")){
    panel.updateUI();
    panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
}
if(opcion.equals("Amarillo")){
    panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
}
if(opcion.equals("Blanco")){
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> solo es efectivo cuando lo realizo como primera opción del mismo
> JComboBox.

Al arrancar la aplicación efectivamente cambia el color de fondo, el agravante es que eso solo se hará una sola vez y nada mas por la manera en que esta planteado en el código fuente; para solucionar eso simplemente es cuestión de ponerle un `actionListener` a `fondoPanel` para que de ese modo sea capaz de efectuar los cambios conforme a la opción que haya sido seleccionada.

En ese orden de ideas, se puede modularizar un poquito el código así:

```
public void colocarComboBox(){
  // ...

  //cambio de fondo
  String [] Fondo ={"Negro","Azul","Amarillo","Blanco"};
  fondoPanel = new JComboBox(Fondo);
  fondoPanel.addActionListener(e->changeBGColor());
  //String opcion = fondoPanel.getSelectedItem().toString();
  fondoPanel.setBounds(320,10,100,30);
  panel.add(fondoPanel);
  changeBGColor();
}

private void changeBGColor() {
  String opcion = fondoPanel.getSelectedItem().toString();
  if(opcion.equals("Negro")){
    //panel.updateUI();
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
  }
  if(opcion.equals("Azul")){
    //panel.updateUI();
    panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
  }
  if(opcion.equals("Amarillo")){
    panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
  }
  if(opcion.equals("Blanco")){
    panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que solo te falta agregar `panel.show()` para cada opción, aunque es recomendable que cambies los **if's** por un **switch**.

Espero te sea de ayuda, y en caso que no te funcione, espero te ayude este tutorial [Tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-swing-jpanel-examples/), y siempre lee la documentación de [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

Answer (score 0):

Te falta agregar un oyente al comboBox para que sepa cuando hay un cambio en las opciones a escoger agregandole fondoPanel.addActionListener, asi te quedaria el codigo.

```
private void colocarCombo() {
    fondoPanel = new JComboBox();
    String[] fondo = {"Negro", "Azul", "Amarillo", "Blanco"};
    fondoPanel = new JComboBox(fondo);
    fondoPanel.setBounds(120, 10, 200, 30);
    panel.add(fondoPanel);

    fondoPanel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { //Oyente de accion para saber que opcion escogiste
            String opcion = fondoPanel.getSelectedItem().toString();
            switch (opcion) { //Swtich evalua la opcion y pinta el panel dependiendo el color de cada caso
                case "Negro" :
                    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
                    break;
                case "Azul":
                    panel.setBackground(Color.blue);
                    break;
                case "Amarillo":
                    panel.setBackground(Color.yellow);
                    break;
                case "Blanco":
                    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

PD: Le hice un cambio de los if por switch.